# How to do InverseDynamics with a floating base robot?

Tags: drake

I tried with the `CalcInverseDynamics`, but the returned `tau` is an 18 dimension vector, 6(floating base) + 12(actuator), which is supposed to be 12 (equal with the num of actuators). Is there any example to do InverseDynamics with the floating-base robot using `known_vdot` and `contact force` trajectories?

I tried with the `LittLeDog.urdf` model. My code is:

```
    def DoID():

        legs = [plant.GetBodyByName("front_left_lower_leg"),
                plant.GetBodyByName("front_right_lower_leg"),
                plant.GetBodyByName("back_left_lower_leg"),
                plant.GetBodyByName("back_right_lower_leg")]
        contacts = [foot_frame[0].CalcPoseInBodyFrame(plant_context).translation() for i in range(4)]
        F_expected = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
        forces = MultibodyForces(plant)

        # add SpatialForce applied to legs into MultibodyForces
        for i in range(4):
            legs[i].AddInForce(
                plant_context, p_BP_E=contacts[i],
                F_Bp_E=SpatialForce(F=F_expected),
                frame_E=plant.world_frame(), forces=forces)

        nv = plant.num_velocities()
        vd_d = np.zeros(nv)
        tau = plant.CalcInverseDynamics(plant_context, vd_d, forces)

        return tau
```

---

update:
at the `CalcInverseDynamics` [API](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#afcb4de9b58cb375d056da7e8ec30937a), it writes:
`tau = M(q)v̇ + C(q, v)v - tau_app - ∑ J_WBᵀ(q) Fapp_Bo_W`

This should also work for the floating-base robot, with the form of
[image]
from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.06586), different notation but the same equation. I hope when the `contact force` and the `known_vdot` (or `qddot`) are 'reasonable', then the [image] will become zeros, and the [image] become the joint torque commands. I will use APIs like `CalcMassMatrix`, `CalcBiasTerm` and `CalcGravityGeneralizedForces` to get [image].

After get the joint commands, use PD controller or other controller to apply to robot. A functional solution to 'controller a desired acceleration' may still need to formulate a QP like http://groups.csail.mit.edu/robotics-center/public_papers/Kuindersma13.pdf. But will try the simpler way first.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are trying to find a controller that will (approximately) follow a desired acceleration of the entire state vector using only the actuators (for littledog, you have 12 actuators, but 19 positions / 18 velocities)?

In addition, with a legged robot like littledog, you have to think about the contact forces (and their friction cones).

The most common generalization of the inverse dynamics control for situations like this involves solving a quadratic program (using a linearization of the friction cone constraints).  See for instance http://groups.csail.mit.edu/robotics-center/public_papers/Kuindersma13.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!  I am trying to control the littledog model, for example, standing. I have got `q`, `v`, `contact point` and `contact force`, then I want to calculate the joint torque, to feed into `plant.get_actuation_input_port()` (or to a controller, then connect to a plant).  My question is how to get these joint torque commands.

Comment: As it is standing, the desired acceleration is zeros. And I don't mean to control the desired acceleration, just want a mapping function to get the joint commands, then use some simpler way to control the robot.

Comment: InverseDynamics is fundamentally about solving for torques to achieve a desired acceleration.  It sounds like you might want something simpler.  The littledog notebook also has a PD controller that makes the robot stand up.

Comment: Yes, I want to computer a joint torque feedforward term, and then use the PD controller to control the robot. I update my post to calculate joint torque, hope that I am not too wrong.